# How to get column name in VBA?

Tags: sql, database, vba, excel

I have created a module where I am reading the data from SQL DB using a stored procedure and I am getting all the required data, but my requirement is that I also needs all the column name/headers too. And I can't hardcode the name because I am converting the data rows into columns in stored procedure.

Here is the code I have written:

```
ConnStr = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB.1;"
ConnStr = ConnStr & "DATA SOURCE=" & dataSrc & "; INITIAL CATALOG=" & iCatalog & "; "
ConnStr = ConnStr & "User ID = " & dbUserId & "; Password = " & dbPassword

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

DBConn.Open ConnStr

' Create a recordset object.
Dim rsCounter As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsCounter = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim startDate As String, endDate As String, query As String

query = "Exec ReadCntrs 0, '12/01/2011', '12/30/2011'"

With rsCounter
    ' Assign the Connection object.
    .ActiveConnection = DBConn

    .Open query
    ' Copy the records into cell A1 on Sheet1.
    Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rsCounter

    ' Tidy up
    .Close
End With

DBConn.Close
Set rsCounter = Nothing
Set DBConn = Nothing

ExitHere:
    On Error Resume Next
    DBConn.Close: Set DBConn = Nothing
    Err.Clear
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHere

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
With rsCounter
    ' Assign the Connection object.
    .ActiveConnection = DBConn

    .Open query

    ' Write the column names into cell A1 on Sheet1.
    Dim counter As Long
    For counter = 0 To rsCounter.Fields.Count - 1
      Sheet1.Range("A1").Offset(, counter).Value = rsCounter.Fields(counter).Name
    Next

    ' Copy the records into cell A2 on Sheet1.
    Sheet1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rsCounter

    ' Tidy up
    .Close
End With
```

Answer (score 4):

`rsCounter.Fields(i).Name` -- where i is an integer representing the field number-- is normally how you access the field name.

EDIT - also, to get the total number of fields you will use `rsCounter.Fields.Count`